# Order by then count and select Max by group, performance issue

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to group by a list, then count the items in each group and then select only the maximum values for each group based on its count. The following code works and does exactly what I need. The problem is that it's very slow, especially the second step. Do you know a way to achieve the same result in a more efficient way?

```
var grouppedList = sourceList.Where(j => j.field1 == "1000")
    .GroupBy(i => new { mask = i.field2.Substring(0, 1), f3 = i.field3, f4 = i.field4 })
    .Select(k => new
    {
        f4 = k.Key.f4,
        mask = k.Key.mask,
        f3 = k.Key.f3,
        Total = k.Count()
    });

var totalsList = grouppedList
    .Where(i => !grouppedList.Any(j => 
                       j.mask == i.mask && j.f4 == i.f4 && j.Total > i.Total))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: did you try to create the list on the first section so that the count will be done once only?

Comment: What _second_ step? There is only one query and it gets executed at `ToList`

Comment: Thanks Tim! This was exactly the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `groupedList` is not a `List`. It is a `IEnumerable`. So it is executed each time you access it. And you acces it for every part of it (in `Where` clause). I would suggest to create a list from it (execute query just once):

```
var grouppedList = sourceList.Where(j => j.field1 == "1000")
    .GroupBy(i => new { mask = i.field2.Substring(0, 1), f3 = i.field3, f4 = i.field4 })
    .Select(k => new
    {
        f4 = k.Key.f4,
        mask = k.Key.mask,
        f3 = k.Key.f3,
        Total = k.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

Another possibility is to combine grouping and getting item with the most Total, i would do it something like this:

```
var grouppedList = sourceList.Where(j => j.field1 == "1000")
.GroupBy(i => new { mask = i.field2.Substring(0, 1), f3 = i.field3, f4 = i.field4 })
.Select(k => new
{
    f4 = k.Key.f4,
    mask = k.Key.mask,
    f3 = k.Key.f3,
    Total = k.Count()
})
.GroupBy(x => new {x.mask, x.f4})
.Select(x=>x.OrderBydescending(t=>t.Total).First());
.ToList();
```

Comment: @Manngo if it helped you, i would be thankfull for an upvote :)

Comment: I would definitely use the second approach (or similar) +1

Answer (score 1):

The reason this code seems slow is probably the fact that you´re iterating `grouppedList` twice.

```
var totalsList = grouppedList.Where(i => !grouppedList.Any(
    j => j.mask == i.mask && j.f4 == i.f4 && j.Total > i.Total)
).ToList();
```

Will iterate `groppedList` in the inner `Where`-statement for all elements in `groppuedList`. You may consider to force an immediate execution with `ToList` for eample:

```
var grouppedList = sourceList.Where(j => j.field1 == "1000")
.GroupBy(i => new { mask = i.field2.Substring(0, 1), f3 = i.field3, f4 = i.field4 })
.Select(k => new
{
    f4 = k.Key.f4,
    mask = k.Key.mask,
    f3 = k.Key.f3,
    Total = k.Count()
}).Tolist();    // this forces an immediate execution of your select-statement
```

When you now call your second statement

```
var totalsList = grouppedList.Where(i => !grouppedList.Any(j => j.mask == i.mask && j.f4 == i.f4 && j.Total > i.Total)).ToList();
```

it will use the allready materialized lists instead of executing the query again and again.